# How to Emulate Google Glass GDK Gestures on an Android AppUpdate uj

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am just starting a new application for my android phone. I would like to get some basic functionality like making Google Glass handle some gestures.

I don't know which function to call in order for glass to handle a Tap, SWIPE_LEFT or SWIPE_RIGHT.

For example lets say I would like to start my app and have it do a SWIPE_RIGHT two times. How do I accomplish this from an android Application? It would be very much like Screencast!

Comment: Please read the documentation and come back when you have a more specific question. I'm not trying to be rude, it's just: that's one of the first things they cover.

Comment: I've read that page: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/package-summary

I don't understand where they have Google glass handle the gestures.I know that "GestureDetector.BaseListener" receives the results of what gestured just happened but does this have glass handle that gesture?

Comment: Oh! I get your question now. You're asking how GlassHome implements this. Gotcha. So you're asking how to implement this on an Android app, and not in a Glass app, correct?

Comment: Correct! :) I would like to implement this on an Android app. And its not that I want to personally handle the Gesture I just want to pass Google Glass some gesture without physically having to touch the glass.

Answer (score 0):

in Google Glass

1)  [GestureDetector](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector) are used to get gestures from touchpad on Glass.

2)  [GestureDetector](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector) then have [Different Listeners](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/package-summary)

3)  You override GenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) and pass it to your  [GestureDetector](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector)

4)  As per UI Guidelines in glass you work with one at thing at a time so.

**Example Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GestureDetector detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
detector = new GestureDetector(this);
detector.setBaseListener(new BaseListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGesture(Gesture arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        openOptionsMenu();
        if(arg0== Gesture.TAP)
        {
            Log.e("MyLog", "you tapped");
            Card card=new Card(MainActivity.this);
            card.setText("This is a card");
            card.addImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            TimelineManager.from(MainActivity.this).insert(card);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("MyLog","You "+arg0.name());
        }
        return true;
    }
});
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        detector.onMotionEvent(event);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I do NOT want to override any of the GestureDetector Events. I want to create an app like Screencast.  I would like to send a gesture from my android app to glass in order to navigate through the menus from my phone.

Comment: @Overtim3 . No one understood that because glass application are also android applications you need to mention that you want to do it from android phone. Then i might makes sense. Am i Right ?